# Error converting data type nvarchar to int in multiple Pivot on same column SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I am trying to use multiple pivot in a single query on same column.
Since i am using same column "month" for all the pivot's, i have added column header to the select list and have added different alias name. Month column has int datatype value. Below is the code:

```
    Select * FROM  
    (
    SELECT 
    [team], 
    Count_O,
    Count_Of_OA,
    Avg,
    [month]+ '_a'  as month_a, 
    [month] + '_b' as month_b,
    [users]  
    FROM [#Temp]
    ) AS X 

    PIVOT  
(  
    MAX(Count_OA)
    FOR [month_a] IN ([4_a], [5_a], [6_b])  
)   AS PivotTable1

PIVOT  
(  
    MAX(Count_O)
    FOR [month_b] IN ([4_b], [5_b], [6_b])  
)   AS PivotTable2
```

When i execute this, I get the below error:
Msg 8114, Level 16, State 1, Line 44
Error converting data type nvarchar to int.

Any inputs would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Select * FROM  
    (
    SELECT 
    [team], 
    Count_O,
    Count_Of_OA,
    Avg,
    Convert(varchar(max),[month])+ '_a'  as month_a, 
    Convert(varchar(max),[month]) + '_b' as month_b,
    [users]  
    FROM [#Temp]
    ) AS X 

PIVOT  
(  
    MAX(Count_OA)
    FOR [month_a] IN ([4_a], [5_a], [6_b])  
)   AS PivotTable1

PIVOT  
(  
    MAX(Count_O)
    FOR [month_b] IN ([4_b], [5_b], [6_b])  
)   AS PivotTable2
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Worked!! Appreciate your input!!

Comment: I have a question. Is it advisable to use many pivot's in a single query?

Comment: really depends on the use case.

Comment: While geting the o/p for the months i am getting it as 

    ' subteams        4_a   5_a   6_a
      red                  10
      red                           20
        red                                    30'
 i would like o have the o/p as 

    'subteam      4_a     5_a     6_a
    red               10       20        30'

I mean the o/p in the same row and not as in 3 different rows. any i/ps?